# CSS change a class display by checking some checkbox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying changing a CSS class property by checking a checkbox, but it doesn't work... Can you help me?

My code:

```
<body>
<style>
    #test:checked~#title {
        display: none;
    }

    .reverse-flexbox {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <div class="reverse-flexbox">
        <h1 id="title">Just a text</h1>
        sky is blue
    </div>
    <div class="reverse-flexbox">
        <h1 id="title">Just a text</h1>
        i like stackoverflow
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="test" />
    <h1 id="title">Just a text</h1>
    <div>Something else</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` only works for the downward siblings which are below the element `#test`. `#title` is above `#test`, so that's why your styles do not apply.

If you don't want to change element positions, and still want to use `~`, you can move `#title` up for style application, and then use the reverse directions of the flexbox to show `#title` is above `#test` (only in display).

For multiple `h1` case, you also need to add them below `#test` checkbox

```html
<html lang="pt-br">

<body>
  <style>
    #test:checked~div > #title {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .reverse-flexbox {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column-reverse;
      align-items: flex-start;
    }
  </style>
  <div>
     <div class="reverse-flexbox">
       <input type="checkbox" id="test" />
       <div>
          <h1 id="title">Just a text 1</h1>
       </div>
       <div>
          <h1 id="title">Just a text 2</h1>
       </div>
       <div>
          <h1 id="title">Just a text 3</h1>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div>Something else</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If i have many sub divs, how can i do? Ex:

  <div class="reverse-flexbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="test" />
    <h1 id="title">Just a text</h1>
<div>
<h1 id="title">test2</h1>
<div>
<h1 id="title">test3</h1>
</div>
</div>
  </div>

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can group them according to your needs. By the way, I updated my answer for your sub-div case @Antharaz

Comment: I think i was not clear in my comment... if i have 2 different divs with a h1 and want to hide all h1, i'll have to make one checkbox for each?

Comment: Could you update that HTML in your question? That would help to understand your situation though. @Antharaz

Comment: Done :) Something like the new code... i want hide all h1 with one checkbox

Comment: You can try the above answer again, @Antharaz

Comment: I can't put all h1 in one div like u did, i wnat put more information on divs that i'll not hide, i'll hide only the h1

Comment: I added `div` wrappers for your case. Hopefully, it will fit your needs :D @Antharaz

Answer (score 1):

You have to use input tag first then you can use another html tag to make checked pseudo class working and you can use flexbox to order the html tags.

```css
.form_group{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
} 
#test{
  order: 2;
}
#title{
  order: 1;
}
#test:checked~#title {
      display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form_group">   
  <input type="checkbox" id="test" />
<h1 id="title">Just a text</h1> 
</div>
```

Comment: If i have many sub divs, how can i do? Ex: <div class="reverse-flexbox"> <input type="checkbox" id="test" /> <h1 id="title">Just a text</h1> <div> <h1 id="title">test2</h1> <div> <h1 id="title">test3</h1> </div> </div> </div>

Comment: use one wrapper of input and h1 tag which will help to order the html tags